# how to block a website forever without reverting?

Tags: windows, browser, blocking, ublock

there are many extensions for this. but the extensions themselves can be undone.
I wonder if it's possible to just ban and not be able to play any games in browser..

Comment: Short answer: No - unless you give some else admin access to your computer and remove your own admin access.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=block+website